# MYSQL - PHP - Update value in database by using variable passed from submit button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to know if it possible to pass a value from database as seen below into my php file and UPDATE the corresponding row value based on this passed paramater. For example, When user clicks the button, this will update value inside database based on the id of where the button is located. Thank you.

```
 <?php

// Selecting Database 

include_once 'dbh.php';

//Here we fetch the data from the URL that was passed from our HTML form
$userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];

$jobiD = $_POST['jobID'];


$sql =  "UPDATE jobPost SET emailTeacher='$userEmail' WHERE jobID= ('".$jobID."');";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>
```

AJAX -

```
 function myFunctionjobStatus() {
    var jobID = document.getElementById("jobID").value;


    //AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/EduSubOct/jobstatus.php",
        data: { userEmail: localStorage.getItem("email"), 'jobID': 
jobID }, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert("Request Sent");

        }
    });

}
```

[See attached iamge of code -codeblock wont work for me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I74cK.png)

Comment: Take `'jobID'` out of quotes - you've made it a string instead of a variable.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. Read more about using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables are case-sensitive you know?

```
$jobiD = $_POST['jobID'];
```

**$jobiD** should be **$jobID** as you used it on your query string:

```
$sql =  "UPDATE jobPost SET emailTeacher='$userEmail' WHERE jobID= ('".$jobID."');";
```